# Getting unwanted rows as result in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-10

I am executing the SPARQL query to get the list of productid.

Query:

```
SELECT ?productid
FROM <product>
WHERE {
  ?productid ?p ?o
}
```

this query was executed successfully without any error but the result is not relevant to my requirement.

Please check sample output of above query.

Output: `Returned a solution with 86136 items` 86136 is wrong number here, I don't have these many records in MarkLogic.

```
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/000396767A420BD6>
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/000729A363E21B21>
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/001B177E73C0C077>
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/0020608889124C82>
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/0027EEAF577B24DC>
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/002A6D5028335C94>
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/0038B0B5456A8A2A>
<http://marklogic.com/row/04C5D15B90A0F6A8/004AB1A5FC06B698>
```

TDE used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
    <context>product</context>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <collections>
        <collection>product</collection>
    </collections>
    <triples>
        <triple>
            <subject>
                <val>sem:iri(productid)</val>
                <invalid-values>ignore</invalid-values>
            </subject>
            <predicate>
                <val>sem:iri(xs:string("languageCode"))</val>
                <invalid-values>ignore</invalid-values>
            </predicate>
            <object>
                <val>sem:iri(languageCode)</val>
                <invalid-values>ignore</invalid-values>
            </object>
        </triple>
        <triple>
            <subject>
                <val>sem:iri(productid)</val>
                <invalid-values>ignore</invalid-values>
            </subject>
            <predicate>
                <val>sem:iri(xs:string("countryCode"))</val>
                <invalid-values>ignore</invalid-values>
            </predicate>
            <object>
                <val>sem:iri(fn:normalize-space(xs:string(countryCode)))</val>
                <invalid-values>ignore</invalid-values>
            </object>
        </triple>
    </triples>
</template>
```

My requirement is to get the `productid` list without any unwanted rows.

Comment: Maybe I 'm missing something in your question, but your query does not return the "number of items" but the number of bindings in triples matching your query. Indeed having mulitple triples with the same `productid` leads to repeated rows. If you just want a distinct set of items, use the `DISTINCT` operator: `SELECT DISTINCt ?productid`